# Saving the state of objects at specific keyframe

Tags: modeling, objects, physics, keyframes, timeline

I am trying to create a game asset in blender and for better accuracy and in order to be more realistic, I am using the physics tool for the asset I am trying to make.

However upon interacting with the rigid body option and the settings being dynamic for the meshes involved, I cannot move or copy/save the state of the meshes at the specific keyframe I need after it starts and I need to be able to have it in a specific formation.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: A non-destructive way would be to play the animation through and at the frame you wish to 'freeze' the model, duplicate it and ---> WITHOUT <--- moving the timeline further, clear it's animation in the Outliner, them remove it's physics and any other contraints or modifiers.  You end up with a copy that's frozen in the action pose at that frame.

If the physics engine varies the original's motions after that, do as above but from a duplicate Blend file.  Append (import) the frozen model back into the original file.

Comment: Like you mentioned I have tried different methods when the frame is frozen, duplicating, copying, using even 3 different blender programs in order to paste them in. Turn off the physics. But each time I am having the models in a random place, stacked on top of each other or pasted in before the animation has taken place. I will keep trying to work something out. It would also be extremely difficult to remove the physics one by one from the asset as there are many similar meshes involved.

Comment: I have figured it out, posting answer soon.

Comment: Glad to see you have it sorted :)

Answer (score 1):

I have found that here is a quick an easy solution to this problem.

1. Play the animation of the physics and stop at the required frame.
2. **Select** the objects you would like to save the state during interaction with physics.
3. Navigate to *[top left {near object mode}]* **Object**
4. From the drop down select **Rigid Body**
5. **Apply Transformation**
6. Preferably duplicate or copy the object then (optional) and save in different file.

I recommend doing this no matter the mesh count and saves a lot of time, if you have any other ways to go around this issue please leave another answer or comment.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out recently, had to share, it was making me crazy.

Run the animation > pause at desired keyframe > select the object you want to save > Navigate to File > Export (Export whatever file type you need) > Check "Selected Objects" and "Apply transformation" boxes > name it > hit Export > now you have an object file of the saved animated keyframe with all your physics.

good luck.